# Windows script delete specific subfolders inside a path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I need your help for writing a little batch script in order to delete specific named folders inside a path.

Let's image we have multiple folders called `"pippo"` inside the path tree `"C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\StartFolder"`

How can I write a script that browses all the folder tree of that path and delete all fsubolders called `"pippo"` ?

Thanks!

---

I found this command in other site 
    `for /d /r "%d" %d in (_svn) do @if exist "%d" rmdir "%d"`

So I tried to adapt it to my target, but it doesn't work.
    `for /d /r "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\StartFolder" "pippo" in (_svn) do @if exist "pippo" rmdir "pippo"`

Comment: The way SO works is that you show the code you have been trying, describe what it should be doing, and describe how it is failing. SO is not a free script writing service.

Comment: Ok, sorry, i'll provide what I tried until now.

Comment: What happens to any directories or files within the pippo directory tree?

Comment: It has to be removed. But answer below solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what the `_svn` is meant for in your tries.
( or is `_svn`
your real `pippo` ?)

```
for /r "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\StartFolder" /d %%A in (pippo
     ) do if exist "%%~fA" echo rmdir "%%~fA"
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `echo` in front of `rmdir`

Sample output on my test tree:

```
> for /r "q:\Test\2018" /D %A in (05) do @if exist "%~fA" @echo rd "%~fA"
rd "q:\Test\2018\05"
rd "q:\Test\2018\04\05"
rd "q:\Test\2018\05\05"
```

Comment: I thought the `/D` option required a wildcard!

Comment: @Compo I did a test and included it in my answer.

Comment: Ok, this works! I did not understand that "(_svn)" was the name of the name of the folder I wanna delete.

Comment: @compo it simply appends to the path from `/r` if present or not, so an if exist is necessary.

Comment: As long as no wildcard is used, `for [/R]` does not access the file system and just returns the item(s) after `in`, so `/D` is not needed but does not harm either; usually I do add `/D` in case directories are to be processed just for indication...